# Why hasn't Boeing updated the 747 with technology from the 787?

Tags: aircraft-design, commercial-aviation, boeing-747, boeing-787

Why hasn't Boeing updated the 747 with technology/designs from the 787 Dreamliner? Surely this would be a very successful aircraft as it could have the best of both designs.

Has Boeing explained why? Are there any reasons this couldn't or shouldn't be done?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They did, in the [747-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_747-8):

Wikipedia:

> Similar in nature to the 747X, the stretched 747 Advanced **used technology from the Boeing 787 Dreamliner to modernize the design and its systems**. On November 14, 2005, Boeing announced that it was launching the 747 Advanced as the "Boeing 747-8"

(Emphasis mine)

The 747-8 includes technology in the cockpit, cabin, wings, and engines borrowed or learned from the 787 and 777 aircraft programs. Obviously you can't just pull the wings off of a 787 and stick them on a 747, but the wings were redesigned with aerodynamic information learned in the 777/787 program.

Comment: Have they increased the window size and made them electronically dimming? Also is the cabin pressurised to a higher level, @RonBeyer

Comment: @SRawes Yes, the windows are larger, but I'm not sure if they are electronically dimming. If you want to read about the similarities between the 787 interior and the 747-8 interior, [here is a good read with a video](http://www.modernairliners.com/boeing-747-8/boeing-747-8i-and-8f-interior/).

Comment: I think it really comes down to money, there isn't enough demand for planes in the 747 size category to justify a clean-sheet design with a composite fuselage.

Comment: The are not electronically dimming on the 747-8. But much bigger and that's a nice thing for passengers :)